# teamcity remote run custom parameters

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to provide custom parameters for TC remote run?
For example I have a 'deploy' build configuration and each developer would like to deploy to his own 'host'.
I can easily make 'host' build parameter and user will be prompted to populate the value on 'Run' button click.
Is it feasible for remote run to use different 'host' parameter for each user?

Edit:
I'm using Eclipse with TC plugin. There is no context menu on Remote Run window on right click.

Comment: What version of TeamCity are you using? The documentation for v8 (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Eclipse+Plugin) says the Eclipse plugin supports "customizing parameters for personal builds". Once you've selected the changes to push out, can you not right click on the build configurations?

Comment: TeamCity Professional 8.1.2 (build 29993)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you are using the Visual Studio plugin to push out remote builds you can right click on a build configuration and select 'Customize build'. This will show a dialog with parameter name/value pairs where the value is editable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make a template from the build and not specify the 'host' build parameter in the template and then create a build for each dev with specific value for the dev specific 'host'.